# Oprofile install on ubuntu 15.04 - no binary found in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oprofile

I am trying to install oprofile on my ubuntu 15.04 by following the link:

[Getting started with oprofile on Ubuntu](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.tw/2013/05/getting-started-with-oprofile-on-ubuntu.html)

On my the other laptop whcih is running on ubuntu 14.04, it works well.

I can find the binary under /usb/bin directory.

However, I dont know why after typing the apt-get command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oprofile
```

My ubuntu 15.04 still doesn't have oprofiled & opcontrol binary in /usr/bin.

Is there anyway I could check with?

Thanks

===================post updated =======================
[image]

Comment: Can you try with `which oprofiled` or `which opcontrol` ?

Comment: Just tried and it shows nothing.

Comment: does those packages installed successfully or not ? if not any error or something ?

Comment: those packages were installed successfully.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep oprofile` check with this if its installed ?

Comment: @juned I think it has been installed but I just have no idea why the binary is disappeared. Post updated.

Comment: have you tried remove this package first then reinstall it ?

Comment: Vivid comes with oprofile 1.0.0, which no longer uses the opcontrol and oprofiled commands. If you want to follow that tutorial, install 0.9.9 from source code.

Comment: @kaitian, yes, I tried to re-install it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick this makes sense to this question. would you post you reply in the answer so that I can check ? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 [comes with](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/devel/oprofile) oprofile 1.0.0, which [no longer](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/release-notes/oprofile-1.0.0) uses the `opcontrol` and `oprofiled` commands. If you want to follow that tutorial, install 0.9.9 from source code. [oprofile download page on SourceForge](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/download/).